# Displaying Images from DataLoader with TensorFlow Lite Model Maker

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, dataloader, image-classification

I am following the tutorial for creating an image classifier using the TensorFlow Lite Model Maker found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification#simple_end-to-end_example. Even though I am following the tutorial exactly, I can't images from the loaded data sets to display. Here's the relevant code and error message:
[error code: AttributeError: 'ImageClassifierDataLoader' object has no attribute 'dataset'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejlf.png)

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

```
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(data.dataset.take(25)):
  plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(image.numpy(), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
  plt.xlabel(data.index_to_label[label.numpy()])
plt.show()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-160e876048da> in <module>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
----> 2 for i, (image, label) in enumerate(data.dataset.take(25)):
      3   plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
      4   plt.xticks([])
      5   plt.yticks([])

AttributeError: 'ImageClassifierDataLoader' object has no attribute 'dataset'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/commit/f3ef104a579953de06bdc6b4342d6963a9d93556#diff-64080f8651eaae5229355acb9ef27ffe55a8d59ac82d6115fa17cc0667e97ab9) they hide `dataset` from you, now you should use `gen_dataset()` method to get one:

```
ds = data.gen_dataset()
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(ds.take(25)):
  plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(image.numpy(), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
  plt.xlabel(data.index_to_label[label.numpy()])
plt.show()
```

It would be nice if you fill ticket for them to edit colab notebook.